# Setting up Emacs as Python editor

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

I have installed the elpy going through [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) and the elpy site. My problem is when i run `M-x elpy-config` i get the following page opened up:

```
Elpy Configuration

Virtualenv........: None
RPC Python........: 2.7.6 (/usr/bin/python)
Interactive Python: python (/usr/bin/python)
Emacs.............: 24.4.1
Elpy..............: 1.10.0
Jedi..............: 0.9.0
Rope..............: Not found (0.10.3 available)
Importmagic.......: 0.1.3
Autopep8..........: 0.1.3
Syntax checker....: Not found (pyflakes)
```

**You have not activated a virtual env. While Elpy supports this, it is
often a good idea to work inside a virtual env. You can use M-x
pyvenv-activate or M-x pyvenv-workon to activate a virtual env.
The directory ~/.local/bin/ is not in your PATH. As there is no active
virtualenv, installing Python packages locally will place executables
in that directory, so Emacs won't find them. If you are missing some
commands, do add this directory to your PATH.
The configured syntax checker could not be found. Elpy uses this
program to provide syntax checks of your programs, so you might want
to install one. Elpy by default uses flake8.
`[run] pip install --user flake8`**.

Now i have installed flake8 (if i try it again i get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flake8 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...).
```

Also when i do `C-x C-b` i don't see any RPC under processes.
Last thing why i get python 2.7.6 there, despite the fact that i have aliased my default python to be python 3.4 with `alias python=python3` in ~/.bash_aliases? I get Python 3.4.3 if i ask `python -V` in the terminal, but not in emacs.
Can any one help?